# My Website is consuming all of the HTTP concurrent connections

Tags: javascript, vb.net, http

With a recent increase in website traffic, I'm experiencing HTTP 503 errors.  I contacted my hosting company and they informed me that my application is consuming all of the HTTP concurrent connections.  They advised that I scour the codes and ensure that all HTTP calls, both Inbound and Outbound, are being closed correctly by the application.

Knowing little about this, my two questions as I try to figure out where to look for the culprit:

1st - I use the below code (one or the other on a page, not both) on most pages to redirect to a secure page or to redirect away from a secure page.  Is there any reason that this particular piece of code would be causing the problem?

```
        If Request.IsSecureConnection Then
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("https://", "http://"))
        End If

        If Request.IsSecureConnection Then
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"))
        End If
```

2nd - I have Google Adsense javascript tracking code and a chat / click service javascript tracking code in my master page.  Doesn't that mean each time a visitor moves from page to page they are re-opening those two connections? Is it possible that a visitor clicking on 20 different page views has 20 open connections to both Google and the chat software company?  Or are they closed each time even when they are in the master page?  Or am I way off base with that?  As you can tell, I'm grasping for ideas here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `20 open connections to both Google and the chat software company?` - that wont effect connections to your server though, will it

Comment: Yeah - you're probably correct.  Perhaps it would run through my server if it was an API but not a javascript link.  As I said, I'm grasping for anything here.